# Force APIM to cache when API response contains no-cahce headers

Tags: azure, caching, azure-api-management

I have to implement a poorly designed external API. The responses are more than 3 MB in size and the data changes seldomly.
So I'd like to cache the response. Unfortunately the caching I usually use does not work, always a cache miss and I suspect it has something to do with the headers the API returns.

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

I tried to remove the headers and then cache, but no luck.
The cacheKey is the same for the subsequent calls, I obfuscated parts. Below a part of the trace.

```json
{
    "source": "cache-lookup",
    "timestamp": "2023-12-04T09:30:44.7996246Z",
    "elapsed": "00:00:00.0004388",
    "data": {
        "message": "Cache lookup resulted in a miss. Cache headers listed below were removed from the request to prompt the backend service to send back a complete response.",
        "cacheKey": "3_xx-apim-backend-xxxx.azure-api.net.4_xxx-xxxx-xxxxx-api;rev=1.60849_xxxxxxset_Getsets.85978_8_https_api-xxxxx-test.xxxx.nl_443_/api/xxxx/ore/5?tot=2024-09-01T00%253a00%253a00Z&van=2023-09-01T00%253a00%253a00Z&::Accept=*%2F*",
        "cacheHeaders": []
    }
},
```

This is how my inbound policy looks like:

```xml
<inbound>
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="false" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="internal">
        <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
        <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
        <vary-by-header>Authorization</vary-by-header>
    </cache-lookup>
    <base />
</inbound>
```

And the outbound:

```xml
<outbound>
    <set-header name="Pragma" exists-action="delete" />
    <set-header name="Cache-Control" exists-action="delete" />
    <cache-store duration="86400" />
    <base />
</outbound>
```

So, is it really because of the response headers, or am I missing something else? And if it are the headers, anything I can do to cache the response anyway?

Full response headers from the API that's being called:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 3290270
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(), camera=(), geolocation=(self), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=(), interest-cohort=()
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; frame-src https://player.vimeo.com/; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com [...snip...]
X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 07:59:44 GMT
```

Comment: Maybe removing the header is an option: <set-header name="Cache-Control" exists-action="delete" /> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-header-policy#remove-header

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get `Cache lookup resulted in a hit!` message in Trace by using below policy. Thanks **@Markus Meyer** for the comment.

***Policy***-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="false" downstream-caching-type="none" caching-type="internal">
            <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
            <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
            <vary-by-header>Authorization</vary-by-header>
        </cache-lookup>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <cache-store duration="86400" cache-response="true" />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

*I am getting the below response*-

[image]

***Trace***-

[image]
[image]

Try to remove `<set-header>` from `<outbound>` policy, you will get the result too.

Comment: Tried that (was my initial setup). No luck. I've never had problems implementing cache before. I added the full headers for reference. Does your function return the Cache-Control and Pragma headers?

Comment: @RuSm Yes my function is also returning Cache-Control and Pragma headers in the response. Can you try doing it from scratch?